# Hyperledger Fabric ProcessProposal -> Failed to invoke chaincode channel= chaincode=_lifecycle

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, lifecycle, chaincode

I am running Hyperledger Fabric and while trying to install the chaincode on peer0.org1, "peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz",  I run into some errors and can not install it -- *Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - error in simulation: failed to execute transaction ee4a6ae0672861fa153e7fd5cd797e59b3eeebf1d2950ccd9e13e8231de484a9: error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction.*
Below I will share the logs. Can anyone tell me what should I do? I have tried to reinstall it but with no success.

----logs---

```
2022-08-28 16:10:46.246 UTC 004a INFO [chaincode.externalbuilder.ccaas_builder] waitForExit -> ::Error: chaincode type not supported: node command=detect
2022-08-28 16:14:33.640 UTC 004b WARN [peer.blocksprovider] func1 -> Encountered an error reading from deliver stream: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing channel=mychannel orderer-address=orderer.example.com:7050
2022-08-28 16:14:33.640 UTC 004c WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> Orderer hung up without sending status channel=mychannel orderer-address=orderer.example.com:7050
2022-08-28 16:15:46.750 UTC 004d INFO [endorser] callChaincode -> finished chaincode: _lifecycle duration: 300000ms channel= txID=ee4a6ae0
2022-08-28 16:15:46.778 UTC 004e ERRO [endorser] simulateProposal -> failed to invoke chaincode _lifecycle, error: timeout expired while executing transaction
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*Handler).Execute
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571 channel= txID=ee4a6ae0
2022-08-28 16:15:46.778 UTC 004f WARN [endorser] ProcessProposal -> Failed to invoke chaincode channel= chaincode=_lifecycle error="error in simulation: failed to execute transaction ee4a6ae0672861fa153e7fd5cd797e59b3eeebf1d2950ccd9e13e8231de484a9: error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction"
2022-08-28 16:15:46.778 UTC 0050 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.21.0.1:51150 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=5m0.029919322s
2022-08-28 16:16:03.168 UTC 0051 INFO [lifecycle] InstallChaincode -> Successfully installed chaincode with package ID 'basic_1.0:9821071a953f452bda87fe89637d1e377dac825da4649ba998464a3c85d60c50'
2022-08-28 16:20:33.471 UTC 0052 WARN [peer.blocksprovider] func1 -> Encountered an error reading from deliver stream: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing channel=mychannel orderer-address=orderer.example.com:7050
2022-08-28 16:20:33.471 UTC 0053 WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> Orderer hung up without sending status channel=mychannel orderer-address=orderer.example.com:7050
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide a bit more information about the chaincode you're trying to install (e.g. is it Java, Node, etc.) and the Fabric network you're trying to install it on (e.g. one of the fabric-samples test networks, or something else). Thanks.

Comment: The first line says **chaincode type not supported**, please share the command you issued, the problema might be there.